# Trying to use sendkey

Tags: powershell, powerbi, sendkeys

The first `SendKeys "%H"` is recognized. I see the result in the report. However the "R" is not.

```
Reports\Templates\Sensor_Exporter\Master8.pbix

Start-Sleep -s 15
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic");

[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Master8 - Power BI Desktop");

Start-Sleep -s 5

$wshell.SendKeys("%H")
$wshell.SendKeys("R")
```

Comment: Why not `$wshell.SendKeys("%HR")`

Answer (score 0):

Just had to put start-sleep -s 2 between the two sendkey 
Its working now.